# Chrome silently ignoring single click download of 7z files

Tags: google-chrome, 7-zip

When I press a link to .7z files on Chrome, it is silently getting ignored and the file is not downloaded. There is no pop-up message or any indication of why it's not downloading the file, just nothing happens. I think it used to download normally some time ago, but looks like chrome update or something (Chrome seems to update itself silently) is now blocking this. I don't have any extensions installed. Right clicking the link and clicking Save link as... works correctly. How can I find out what is blocking single-click download of 7z files, and how do I re-enable this feature?

Chrome version: Version 89.0.4389.82 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Is it a ftp:// URL? Can you provide the URL not working?

Comment: I went here:  https://www.7-zip.org/download.html  with Chrome. I click on download and the Save folder I have Chrome prompt me with works fine. (1) are you trying to automate something? Reset the Chrome download options. Does the download work with Chromium Edge?

Comment: Does it work in Incognito mode? I think that disables extensions

Comment: @gregg it's an http://  type link, and it has the same problem in incognito mode

Comment: @John it works in internet explorer and Edge. The 7-zip.org's link to .7z files is also working. Could it be a problem with the webserver? But it does work as expected with other browsers

Comment: Must be a webserver issue if everything else is working fine.

Comment: Try right clicking on the link and choose "save as"

Comment: A few things to check:
1. Please confirm that there's nothing in your Downloads section in Chrome
2. In Chrome Settings, set "Ask where to save each file before downloading" in the Downloads section
3. Open Chrome Developer Tools, go to the Network tab and see if anything happens when you click on the 7z file

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are on a secure website (https), but the download link is to an insecure website (http). Using Chrome, here's what happens when I click a link on https://www.caldigit.com/ts3-plus-support/ that leads to http://downloads.caldigit.com/CalDigit_TS3_Plus_Firmware_Updater.zip:

[image]

I don't think I'd want Chrome to allow this, but it would be good if it issued a warning...